# groupBy() method gives empty result Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Trying to create a request with groupBy() method, but yii2 returns empty result.
This is my action:

```
\Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
$data = MachineLog::find()
            ->select(['sum(value)', 'max(datetime)'])
            ->where([ '<', 'datetime', $end->format('Y-m-d G:i:s') ])
            ->andWhere([ '>', 'datetime', $start->format('Y-m-d G:i:s') ])
            ->andWhere([ 'type' => $type, 'machine_id' => $machineId[0] ])
            ->groupBy(["UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) DIV $diffInSeconds"])
            ->all();
return $data;
```

Raw SQL gives adequate result, request is same as generated by yii2.

```
mysql> SELECT sum(value), max(datetime) FROM `machine_log` WHERE (`datetime` < '2018-05-10 17:00:00') AND (`datetime` > '2018-05-10 16:30:00') AND ((`type`='1') AND (`machine_id`='4')) GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) DIV 180;
+------------+---------------------+
| sum(value) | max(datetime)       |
+------------+---------------------+
|       NULL | 2018-05-10 16:32:52 |
|       NULL | 2018-05-10 16:35:52 |
|       NULL | 2018-05-10 16:38:52 |
|          2 | 2018-05-10 16:41:59 |
|         36 | 2018-05-10 16:44:59 |
|         36 | 2018-05-10 16:47:59 |
|         36 | 2018-05-10 16:50:59 |
|         36 | 2018-05-10 16:53:59 |
|         35 | 2018-05-10 16:56:59 |
|         37 | 2018-05-10 16:59:59 |
+------------+---------------------+
    10 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

Yii Version 2.0.15.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `all()` returns array of models. If you're building custom query like this, with custom columns in `select()`, you need to use [`asArray()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait#asArray()-detail) to force returning rows as array instead of `ActiveRecord` object (which cannot be created form query result).

```
\Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
$data = MachineLog::find()
        ->select(['sum(value)', 'max(datetime)'])
        ->where([ '<', 'datetime', $end->format('Y-m-d G:i:s') ])
        ->andWhere([ '>', 'datetime', $start->format('Y-m-d G:i:s') ])
        ->andWhere([ 'type' => $type, 'machine_id' => $machineId[0] ])
        ->groupBy(["UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) DIV $diffInSeconds"])
        ->asArray()
        ->all();

return $data;
```